# laravel 5 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist'

Tags: laravel

I am using the laravel 5.
But will result in an error message when you try to access the site.
Solution but I do not know how. Do not know anyone solutions?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in /home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php:1029 Stack trace: #0
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(1029): ReflectionClass->__construct('log') #1 
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(980): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array) #2 
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(1493): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array) #3 
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(1072): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Psr\\Log\\LoggerI...') #4 
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(1056): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter)) #5 
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(1042): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array) #6 
/home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php(980): Illuminate\Container\Container->bui in /home/my-project/www/my-project/vendor/compiled.php on line 1029
```

Comment: try ``php artisan clear-compiled``

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem after I made changes to my `.env` file that didn't involve any whitespace. After I rolled back my changes I was fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by adding Double quotation `"` for utf8 characters in **.env** file.

Answer (score 0):

At first try run

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met with the same problem and after some time wasted I figured out that my deploy script ignored the /config directory and didn't copied to the public site.

I've copied the /config directory and everything is fine :)

*(sry for my english :">)*

Answer (score 0):

May be edit you composer.json and remove the following packages:

```
"php-console/php-console": "~3.0",
"php-console/laravel-service-provider": "~5.0"
```

run `composer update` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that I missed single quotes in my .env file. Whenever you specify a constant with a whitespace (in my case 'Webmaster Test') you need to use qoutes around that. Nasty little error!!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

Make sure the php PDO extension is installed correctly.

That worked for me.